# dialog menu - set hotkey colors?

Tags: bash, dialog

I've created a menu system with dialog to launch various programs and OSes in DosBox, VirtualBox, and natively. Almost everything works as well as I could ask. I do have one little cosmetic nit-pic though. When the enumerated(?) menu items exceed a single character, they become multi-color.

I realize this might be a design decision to facilitate grouping of hotkeys. If I start my menu items off as "01", "02", etc,... they're still multi-colored(the zero is red, the second digit is yellow). And if I press "1", it takes me to "10", then "11", etc,...

I can appreciate the ease of this setup, if I have a menu with a large amount of items, I can jump to groups of 10 by pressing "1", or "2", etc,...

I'd just like to remove the visual cue. I'd like the menu items to have the same color. I.E., I'd like both the "1" and the "2" in choice number "12" to be the same color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the colors are configurable.  It sounds like you're talking about the code implemented [here](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/util.c#L676):

```
attrs[3] = tag_key_selected_attr;
attrs[2] = tag_key_attr;
attrs[1] = tag_selected_attr;
attrs[0] = tag_attr;
```

and (the "key" is the detail of interest) there are some examples of configuring colors in the `samples` directory, e.g., this [section](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/samples/slackware.rc#L99):

```
# Tag key color
tag_key_color = button_key_inactive_color

# Selected tag key color
tag_key_selected_color = (RED,BLUE,ON)
```

That is, if you made the various tag-colors the same, the highlighting would go away.

Comment: How can I add this to my menu? Where and how do I add this?

Comment: That's done by customizing an [".rc" file](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-RUN-TIME-CONFIGURATION).  There's no tutorial, but the samples and screenshots should be enough to let you experiment with the feature.

Comment: I had to create a .dialogrc file, and set "tag_color = (RED,WHITE,OFF)". Thank you!

Comment: sounds good (packagers for some distributions use the feature).

Comment: .. you can also achieve this with bash process substitution instead of creating a file: `DIALOGRC=<(echo -e "tag_key_color = tag_color\ntag_key_selected_color = tag_selected_color") dialog …`